# is it possible to specify conditional output bindings?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**Is it possible to conditionally specify bindings?**

I have an azure function:

```
    [FunctionName("OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("httpqueue", Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:SourceQueueConnection")] MyPayload myQueueItem,
        [Blob("processed/{Payload}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] Stream processedPayload,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.Payload}");
    }
```

As you can see, it has a queuetrigger, as well as an output bounding of `Blob("processed/{Payload}"...`

**Is it possible to specify a conditional binding?**

For example:

Trigger output binding *only* if `DateTime.UtcNow` < XYZ?

**Is it possible to conditionally specify bindings?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it's possible to configure name patterns.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---blob-name-patterns

To implement such kind of conditions it's better to look at Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ICollector<T>` on Queue Bindings which gives you control on which messages you want to forward.

Take a look at [ICollector with Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/queue-storage#using-icollector-with-azure-storage-queue-bindings)